# SQL Language -- Is there a way to write average twice?

Tags: sql

The question is "List all payments greater than twice the average payment"

```
SELECT AVG(amount)
FROM Payments
WHERE amount > AVG(amount)*2;
```

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS. Is twice the average payment = `2*AVG(amount)`?

Comment: `SELECT *
FROM Payments
WHERE amount > (SELECT AVG(amount) * 2 FROM Payments)`

Comment: Can't you `SELECT AVG(amount) AS average
FROM Payments
WHERE amount / 2 > average;`? (beware of "integral division" however)

Comment: THANK YOU ALL! PROBLEM SOLVED!

Comment: @JavaQuestions Consider accepting Giorgos Bestos' answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a subquery to calculate the overall average amount:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Payments 
WHERE amount > (SELECT AVG(amount)*2 FROM Payments)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the average in a variable

```
Declare @average int
Select @average = ...
Select * from ... Where x>= @average
```

Comment: I didn't say that... (Did someone downvote? I didn't.)

Answer (score 0):

this query may help you:

```
SELECT * FROM `Payments` WHERE amount > ((select avg(amount) from `Payments`)*2)
```